# Representations of the binary string in the tree graph paths

Tags: python, algorithm, list, pandas, networkx

I'm trying to write an algorithm in which graphs are searched for possible node paths, representing binary strings. Where nodes with even numbers correspond to the digit '0', while the odd numbers '1'. The following code is for the time being unelegant and not optimized. In the code comments I put some explanations for his actions.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("graph.csv", sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
df1=df.astype(int)

g = nx.Graph()
g = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df1, 'nodes_1', 'nodes_2')

plt.show()
# I load any binary string.
# Example '01'
z = input('Write a binary number. \n')

z1=list(z)
l1 = df1['nodes_2'].tolist()

# I add to the list '0', because in df1 ['nodes_2'] the node '0' is missing.
l1[:0] = [0]

# I check whether the first digit entered in the input() of the variable 'z' is 0 or 1.
# And with good values I create a list of 'a'.
a=[]

if int(z1[0])==0:
   for i in l1:
       if i%2==0:
           num1 = int(i)
           a.append(num1)

elif int(z1[0])==1: 
     for i in l1:
        if i%2 ==1:
           num1 = int(i)
           a.append(num1)

else: print('...')

# I am creating 'b' list of neighbors lists for nodes from list 'a'.
b=[]
c=[]

for i in a:
    c.append(i)
    x4 = g.neighbors(i)
    b.append(x4)

# For neighbors I choose only those that are odd in this case,
# because the second digit from the entered 'z' is 1, 
# and then I create a list of 'e' matching pairs representing the possible graph paths.
e=[]

if int(z1[1])==0:
   for j in range(len(b)):
       for k in range(len(b[j])):
          if b[j][k]%2==0:
             d = [a[j], b[j][k]]
             e.append(d)

elif int(z1[1])==1: 
     for j in range(len(b)):
         for k in range(len(b[j])):
             if b[j][k]%2==1:
                d = [a[j], b[j][k]]
                e.append(d)

print (a)
# Output: 
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
print (b)
# Output: 
# [[1, 2], [0, 5, 6], [1, 9, 10], [2, 13, 14], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
print (e)
# Output: 
# [[0, 1], [2, 5], [4, 1], [4, 9], [6, 13], [8, 3], [12, 5]]
```

csv data format:

```
    nodes_1 nodes_2
0   0       1
1   0       2
2   1       3
3   1       4
4   2       5
5   2       6
6   3       7
7   3       8
8   4       9
9   4       10
10  5       11
11  5       12
12  6       13
13  6       14
```

At the present time, I have a problem adjusting the code to use on any long binary string. Because in the above example it is only possible to use a 2-bit string. So I will be very grateful for any tips on simplifying and customizing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code can be reduced to few lines I mean can be vectorized, so you can get rid of for loops i.e

```
a = pd.Series([0] + df['nodes_2'][df['nodes_2']%2==0].values.tolist())

# Creating series to make use of apply 
b = a.apply(g.neighbors)

n1e ,n2e  = df['nodes_1'] % 2 == 0, df['nodes_2'] % 2 == 0
n1o ,n2o = df['nodes_1'] % 2 == 1, df['nodes_2'] % 2 == 1

# Now you want either the nodes_1 be to odd or nodes_2 to be odd but not both, same for even. 
# Use that as a boolean mask for selecting the data 
e = df[~((n1e == n2e) & (n1o == n2o))]
```

Output :

```
a.values.tolist()
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]

b.values.tolist()
[[1, 2], [0, 5, 6], [1, 10, 9], [2, 13, 14], [3], [4], [5], [6]]

e.values.tolist()
[[0, 1], [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 12], [6, 13]]
```

You can take the vectroized code and place it under the respective conditions (boolean values) given by the user.

Updating e based on the condition to keep odd at end and even in the begining i.e

```
e = [[i[0],i[1]] if i[0]%2 == 0 else [i[1],i[0]] for i in e ]
e = pd.DataFrame(e).sort_values(0).values.tolist()

[[0, 1], [2, 5], [4, 1], [4, 9], [6, 13], [8, 3], [12, 5]]
```

Comment: The lists 'a' and 'b' are super, but the 'c' list does not match, I think so. As you can see in the list 'a', the first digit entered in the binary string is even, and therefore the neighbors also agrees.

Comment: But suppose the second digit of the binary string is '0',that's why in the list "e" the second digit in the given pair should be an even number. On the other hand, if the second digit in the binary string is '1', then the second digit in the pair should only be an odd number. Obviously chosen from the right neighbors.
Unless I think badly;)

Comment: Ohk after getting `e` is it ohk to interchange the values based on condition ? I meant would the updated answer help? I still am beginner in networkx will update the solution by the time I get more familiar with it :)

Comment: Now if you are ohk with the solution, give it a thumbs up and accept it ;)

Comment: @ Bharath I still have doubts about the output in 'e'. because it seems to me that I should get `[[0, 1], [2, 5], [4, 1], [4, 9], [6, 13], [8, 3], [12, 5]]`. But maybe I need to get more into the code :)

Comment: I wanted to vectorize the solution and get rid of for loops, so I didn't take sorting into account. Just give me a second let me update the solution if you want sorted output

Comment: My overlook, everything is ok :) Sorting is not so much needed. Once again great thanks :)

Comment: Code updated :). Maybe its a lot to take in to understand but if you execute one line at a time and give much attention you will know the mechanism. Have a good day

Comment: each other :) Thanks!